# Keyword namespace pollution

Tags: common-lisp, symbols

I understand that the difference between

```
(defpackage :foo
  (:export :bar))
```

and

```
(defpackage :foo
  (:export #:bar))
```

is that the latter doesn't intern `bar` into the `KEYWORD` package.  My question is, is there a point in doing this?  It seems like the point of the `KEYWORD` package is to be used for interning keywords, after all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A package is used to maintain namespaces of symbols. A package has a name and symbols have names. Usually one gets these names as strings and thus defpackage forms can use strings for the names:

```
(defpackage "FOO"
  (:export "BAR"))
```

Above package description is not liked by some, since it exposes the case of the identifiers. Usually this is not an issue, but there are non-standard versions of Common Lisp where symbols could be lower-case by default.

Since one can use symbols as names (and only the name is significant) in a `DEFPACKAGE` form we can write:

```
(defpackage :foo
  (:export :bar))
```

or

```
(defpackage #:foo
  (:export #:bar))
```

or even

```
(defpackage cl-user::foo
  (:export cl-user::bar))


CL-USER 22 > (find-symbol "BAR" "FOO")
FOO:BAR
:EXTERNAL
```

The usual expectation is that unreferenced symbols interned in packages might not be removed by a *Garbage Collector* (GC) - the Common Lisp standard says nothing about this topic and has no required behavior. So adding new symbols to a package often keeps it growing. This could be a memory leak in some applications.

Another usual expectation would be that unreferenced *and* uninterned symbols will be freed by a GC.

If you don't mind that there are a *lot* (whatever that means) symbols in the *keyword package*, then it is not an issue.

Typical problems with LARGE packages might be:

- interned symbols may not be GCed
- there MIGHT be some speed cost involved using large packages

For the typical `DEFPACKAGE` form I would not expect any noticeable problem, so one might prefer one variant for whatever stylistic reasons.

Comment: "non-standard versions of Common Lisp": even though the standard specifies what is the default case, it is possible to change it, isn't it?  Assuming variables are set to their default values is generally unsafe. In practice, some libraries in Quicklisp faill to build when defaults are changed.

Comment: @coredump: ANSI Common Lisp requires that (symbol-name 'cl:defun) is "DEFUN" and not "defun" and not "deFun". Some variants of Common Lisp have symbols - even standard CL ones - all downcased internally. The idea is that downcased symbols simplify interoperabilty with external systems.

Comment: Regarding GC, the standard mentions that a package has internal symbols, shadowing symbols and exported symbols.  It is not expected for symbols referred by any of these lists from any live package (i.e. not itself collectible) to be garbage collected.

Comment: The main reason I use uninterned symbols (e.g. `#:symbol`) in `defpackage` is for its name to be read with whatever the current readtable case sensitivity mode is, or implementation-specific case hack mode, something you can't do with a string.  I also prefer an uninterned symbol to a keyword or a qualified or unqualified symbol as to not intern a symbol at read-time, to not store a package name in the compiled file, which also avoids interning at load time and in turn avoids name conflicts.

Comment: @acelent: for example Clozure CL garbage collects unbound interned symbols. Additionally: when creating applications, some Common Lisp implementation may clean up packages and remove unreferenced symbols.

Comment: I understand tree shaking, if it's opt-in, as should be the CCL behavior regarding GC'ing such symbols.